# Toggling an off-canvas menu with addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yii

I'm currently building an Yii application where I want to create my own off-canvas navigation.

It fades in, but I want it to slide in from the left with the transition 0.5s. How can I toggle this with jQuery? Should I use something like `addClass()`?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="menu"> 
  <button id="toggle-menu">Toggle</button>  
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="nav-item"><?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('lunch/home')), 
                array('label'=>'Inschrijven', 'url'=>array('lunch/participate'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),    
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Beheer lunches', 'url'=>array('/lunch/admin'),  'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name=="DeBaas"),
                array('label'=>'Beheer gebruikers', 'url'=>array('/users/admin'),  'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name=="DeBaas"),
                array('label'=>'Log uit ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #666;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    transition: left 0.5s;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 0;
}

#toggle-menu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 320px;
}

.active {
    left: 0!important;
}
```

and my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle-menu").click(function() {
        $('#menu').fade('slow')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sliding with jquery you can use .animate()

something like

```
$('#menu')animate({
   left: "-=300",
}, 500, function() {
   // Animation complete.
});
```